# O que seria o MOJO no Maven?

Tags: maven

Utilizo o [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/index.html) a algum tempo junto com outras ferramentas, e sempre vejo algo relacionado a *Mojo*, o que realmente seria um *Mojo*?

Comment: Eu daria um voto positivo, mas já atingi meu limite por hoje. Boa pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**M**aven plain **O**ld **J**ava **O**bject

Cada MOJO é um goal executável do maven e um plugin é uma distribuição de um ou mais MOJOs.

Ou seja, MOJO é um goal do maven para extender funcionalidades ainda não existentes no maven

---

Fonte: http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/index.html